# PHP: Merge two date objects into one

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've got two date objects sent from a date input and a time input.

I want to generate a DateTime object with the yyyy-mm-dd from the date input and hh-mm from the time input.

Data sent from date input

```
[search_from_date] => 2015-08-04T23:00:00.000Z
```

Data sent from time input

```
 [search_from_time] => 1970-01-01T02:02:00.000Z
```

I need to merge these two dates into:

```
2015-08-04 02:02
```

I've been playing around with exploding the string, etc to no avail,

Any help would be appriciated

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create two DateTime objects from your strings, then use the second to set the time on the first.

```
$arr = ['search_from_date' => '2015-08-04T23:00:00.000Z', 'search_from_time' => '1970-01-01T02:02:00.000Z'];
$date = new DateTime($arr['search_from_date']);
$time = new DateTime($arr['search_from_time']);
$date->setTime($time->format('H'), $time->format('i'), $time->format('s'));
echo $date->format('r');
```

Here's an eval.in with an example - https://eval.in/424209

Comment: Ah awesome, yes this looks correct. Will accept when I test shortly. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

`$finalDateD` creates a date string for just the Year, month and day
and
`$finalDateT` creates a date string for just the Hours, minutes
This is then concatenated into the variable `$finalDate`;

```
$finalDateD = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search_from_date));
$finalDateT = date('H:i', strtotime($search_from_time));
$finalDate = $finalDateD.' '.$finalDateT;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split on "T" like that :

```
$search_from_date = "2015-08-04T23:00:00.000Z";
$search_from_time = "1970-01-01T02:02:00.000Z";

$tab_date = explode("T", $search_from_date);
$tab_time = explode("T", $search_from_time);

$date_time = new DateTime("$tab_date[0]T$tab_time[1]");

var_dump($date_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$search_from_date = '2015-08-04T23:00:00.000Z';
$search_from_time = '1970-01-01T02:02:00.000Z';

$data = explode('T',$search_from_date);
$data1 = explode('T',$search_from_time);
$data1 = explode('.',$data1[1]);

echo $data[0].' '.$data1[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time=new DateTime('1970-01-01T02:02:00.000Z');
$date=new DateTime('2015-08-04T23:00:00.000Z');
$newDateTime= new DateTime();
$newDateTime->setTime($time->format('H'),$time->format('i'),$time->format('s'));
$newDateTime->setDate($date->format('Y'),$date->format('m'),$date->format('d')); 
echo $newDateTime->format('Y/m/d H:i'));
exit;
```